# Android's Material Button size getting reset

Tags: android, material-design, android-button

I am trying to set the background color and stroke color of a Material button through code, but not getting the desired output, its width & height gets changed when I try to do it. Refer to below images:

**Previous**

[image]

**Later**

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
            app:strokeColor="@color/DarkGrey"
            app:strokeWidth="2dp"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="@string/approve"
            android:textSize="@dimen/approve_btn_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

The button is inside the Linear Layout having weightSum = 1.
I also tried using setPadding() and setPaddingRelative(), in order to change width height, but it has no effect
If anyone has any idea why it happens, can you share?

Comment: Which code are you using to change the background and the stroke color?

Comment: btn_approve.backgroundTintList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(mContext!!, R.color.approveBtn )
btn_approve.strokeColor = ColorStateList.valueOf( ContextCompat.getColor( mContext!!, R.color.approveBtnBorder ))

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, the thing that worked for me was to set the android:inset*** parameters to 0dp in the XML file

Reference:

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which API version you are trying to achieve the desired effect. For API 21 and above, the material button draws its corners and stroke (most likely, the **shadow**) in a different way (native way), while below API 21, it adds a padding manually, changes its width / height due to its Java code, hence creating unexpected results.

Comment: My minSdkVersion is 21, so what should be the ideal solution to get the desired ouput?